# Django re_path picking up negative lookahead as capturing group and an argument for the view

Tags: django, regex, url, routes, path

I'm using a urlpattern like so

```py
urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^(?!(?:api/|backend/))', include('an_app.urls')),
]
```

It is so that it doesn't route paths starting with `api/` or `backend/`. I have a specific requirement that needs this pattern, and I can't solely rely on ordering the paths to achieve this (this path captures URLs on `/` and sends them to a view that renders a SPA).

Unfortunately, the Django URL resolver is picking up the negative lookahead (`^(?!...`) as a capturing group, and inserts a path variable into the view. If I run `python manage.py show_urls` (from django-extensions):

```
/<var>app/      an_app.views.SomeView    an_app:home
```

The "group" behind the `^app/` in the regex is not a capturing group, and the paranthesis is there to denote a negative capturing group (i.e. the path doesn't start with `backend/` or `api/`). But it seems like Django is picking it up as a capturing group and inserts a variable into the URL. Do you know how to configure this so it doesn't get picked up?

I have confirmed that using regular python regex (`re.match`) that negative lookahead doesn't get picked up as a group.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but you don't need the non capture group `^(?!api/|backend/)`

Comment: True, thanks. Didn't help in this case, but it did make the regex simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue I was having was that I was trying to reverse a URL to a path in `an_app`. The reverse function couldn't figure out how to construct a URL from a complex regex like the above so it threw an unhelpful error message:

```
Reverse for 'home' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?!api/|backend/)\\Z']
```

I solved this problem by redirecting to the URL rather than the pattern name (and rely on Django to reconstruct the URL).